# 3-manifolds: connected sum & handle decomposition

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Suppose we are given a 2 diagrams for an handle decomposition of two closed, orientable 3-manifold M and $\tilde{M}$. Each of these diagrams consists in an handlebody of genus $g$ (respectively $\tilde{g})$, and  closed curves $\{\gamma_1,\dots, \gamma_g\}$ (respectively $\{\tilde{\gamma}_1,\dots, \tilde{\gamma}_\tilde{g}\})$ drawn on them representing the attacching spheres of the 2-handles.

> How can we construct a diagram of the connected sum $M\#\tilde{M}$  from the given diagrams?

Comment: See the first paragraph of Section 3.2 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0007144.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Arnaud Mortier's comment. As it can be read in paragraph 3.2 Reducible splittings page 9 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0007144.pdf Martin Scharlemann's survey "Heegaard Splittings of compact 3-manifolds", the diagram for the connected sum is obtained just connecting the two handlebodies with a single 1-handle.
Thus the diagram for $M\#\tilde{M}$ consists in an handlebody of genus $g+\tilde{g}$ with the curves $\{\gamma_i\}$ drawn on the first $g$ 1-handles of the handlebody and the curves $\{\tilde{\gamma}_i\}$ drawn on the second set of $\tilde{g}$ 1-handles.

We obtain this by removing cleverly a 3-disk from $M$ that intersects the first handlebody's surface in a 2-disk (thus half of the 3-disk lies in the 3-handle of $M$ and half of it lies in the 1-handlebody induced by the diagram).
We remove similarly a 3-disk from $\tilde{M}$, now we have to glue the new $\mathbb{S}^2$ boundary components, to do so we use a 1-handle to glue two hemispheres and a single last 3-handle to cap the resulting $\mathbb{S}^2$ boundary.

We can also decompose this procedure as follows, first we  add an isolated 2-handle to the diagram of $M$ and the diagram of $\tilde{M}$ (this accounts to removing the  balls). Then we connect the diagrams joining with a 1-handle the  disks bounded by these new 2-handles. We end up with 3 boundary components isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$s. We can cap them with 3-handles.
Reflecting on this construction one sees that the two 2-handles and two 3-handles cancels out thus we have just added a 1-handle and capped all with a single 3-handle.